# Can I move my existing Azure Redis cache from traditional classic Azure subscription to CSP?

Tags: azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-caching

Is there a way I can migrate my traditional subscription created Azure redis cache to CSP subscription and that too under a Vnet? I noticed a statement saying that there is a limitation that It cannot be done.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources

Azure Cache for Redis - if the Azure Cache for Redis instance is configured with a virtual network, the instance can't be moved to a different subscription. See Virtual Networks limitations.

Can anyone help me with this so as to migrate with Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI.

Or do I have to create a new one in the CSP subscription with the same access keys?

Comment: You cannot preserve access keys; any new service you create gets a new set of keys. You cannot set keys either; you can *invalidate* keys (which regenerates new keys for you), but you can never specify the keys.

Comment: thanks. But can I migrate the redis cache to new CSP subscription. if so, can you help me with the links please? Or do I have to create a new one ?

Comment: I don't know what CSP means. And if the docs say you can't migrate, then you can't migrate. But... I'm not quite sure what the need is for migrating Redis, vs just creating a new one, since it's a cache, and isn't really designed to be a primary database.